# Python : compare lists of a list by length and create new lists of equal sizes

Tags: python, list, compare

i have a big list that consists of multiple lists of arbitrary lengths. I want to compare each list length and create new lists of equal sizes. 
For example,

```
biglist = [['x','y','z'],['a','b'],['d','f','g'],...,['r','e','w','q','t','u','i']]
expected_list= [['a','b'],[['x','y','z'],['d','f','g']],....,['r','e','w','q','t','u','i']]
```

I am new to python. can anyone suggest me a less expensive method to do the above process. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have `[[['a','b']], [['x','y','z'],['d','f',g']], ...]` and so on?  Right now your length-2 lists aren't in a separate list of their own, unlike the length-3 lists.  It's like you have `['ab',['xyz','dfg']]` when it would be more consistent to have `[['ab'],['xyz','dfg']]`.

Comment: Are you trying to group together the lists of each given size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest using itertools groupby function?

```
import itertools


biglist = [['x','y','z'],['a','b'],['d','f','g'],['r','e','w','q','t','u','i']]

print(list(list(i[1]) for i in itertools.groupby(sorted(biglist, key=len), len)))
```

Which outputs

```
[[['a', 'b']], [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['d', 'f', 'g']], [['r', 'e', 'w', 'q', 't', 'u', 'i']]]
```

Comment: plus one for the fun. :D

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to `groupby` a list by its element `len`s:

```
>>> biglist = [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'b'], ['d', 'f', 'g'], ['r', 'e', 'w', 'q', 't', 'u', 'i']]
>>> expected_list = [list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(biglist, key=len), len)]
>>> expected_list
[[['a', 'b']], [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['d', 'f', 'g']], [['r', 'e', 'w', 'q', 't', 'u', 'i']]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. hmm.. not just sorting. i want to have new lists of lists of equal sizes. for example, 1st list holds all the lists that have 1 elements... likewise 2nd list holds all the lists of 2 elements. I'm sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: OHH, sorry I didn't notice the extra brackets in your example. will edit

Comment: @ManojFernando, Well I finished my edit, but it looks like Aaron Hall had it before I finished, so he deserves the accept

Comment: :) Thanks for the fun!! Funny how we did it almost identically.

Comment: @AaronHall, the zen of python: one right way to do it